# Como faço para o meu círculo não ser cortado pelo container1?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
    <title>Criar Site</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1>Logomarca</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="circulo">    
            </div>
            <h2><a href="#">Home</a></h2>
            <h2><a href="#">Contato</a></h2>
            <h2><a href="#">Entrar</a></h2>
            <h2><a href="#">Cadastrar</a></h2>
        </div>
        
    </header>
    <div class="container1">

    </div>
    <div class="container2">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap");

*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sidebar{
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #7ec9f5, #3957ed);
    justify-content: left;
    width: 180px;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 998;
}

.logo{
    text-align: center;
}

.sidebar h2{
    position: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 80%;
    display: block;
}

.sidebar a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.circulo{
    background-color: #7ec9f5;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    z-index: 999;
}

.container1{
      z-index: 0;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sua `.sidebar` está com o display errado, troque para `display: flex` e adicione `flex-direction: column`.

E também remova o `margin-left: 150px` do `.circulo`.

Answer (score -3):

Se a ideia for um sidebar tem maneiras melhores de fazer isso mas o problema parece ser a sua margem que ficou muito alta.

Tenta esse valor, aqui centralizou bem.

```
margin-left: 50px;
```